# Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the 'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I get an error when I try to connect to WCF service :

> "Error creating the Web Proxy specified in the
>   'system.net/defaultProxy' configuration section."

I'm using framework 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005.
My web.config content is :

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
        <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

My computer has installed:

- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 SDK-ENU
- ( Framework 1.1 , 3,5 and 4.0 )

I tested :

My current working folder is in a localdriver ,and this folder isn't shared.

I set all permisions to this folder to my current user.

Repair Framework 2.0 ( Windows add and remove programs )

Other people in development team doesn't have problem when connect to WCF.

If I create blank project and try to connect , I get the same error.

Also If I Try to create new blank WCF service and try to connect , I get the same error.

I CAN  show service when I type service url in a browser ( no connection problems )

Firewall and Antivirus software in my local machine is disabled.

If I try to connect to service via svcutil.exe "http://server:8080/Service.svc?wsdl" , I get the same error. ( Can't create web/proxy... )

I suspect that error description doesen't represent the real problem.
What are the main causes of this error?

It's possible that missing some additional software?

Thanks for all in advance!
I'm getting crazy with this error!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps. I faced a similar issue and the problem was due to invalid default Proxy configuration at following location
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG/machine.config

It would depend on the framework you are working against.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for answer.
After long time trying to solve problem, finally I reinstall completely all OS, and works fine!